# First steps with Javascript: trying to debug

Tags: javascript

i have added to the beginning of my code this great script below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

alert("pippo");


</script>
```

And it works: when i load the page it shows a small window with "pippo".

If i I add this below after the alert:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    // validate signup form on keyup and submit


    $("#foo").validate({
        rules: {
            'telephone[number]': {
        number: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'telephone[number]': "Please enter a telephone number"

        }
    });
});
```

and reload the page it doesn't show "pippo" any more..Why?

Regards

Javi

Comment: If you're just getting started with JavaScript, be sure you get yourself tooled up. :-) Chrome and Safari have dev tools built-in, just choose them from the menu (or on Chrome at least, press Ctrl+Shift+I). Firefox has the excellent [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) plug-in available. For debugging in IE, you can use Visual Studio (there's a free edition available for this). Any of these would have flagged up the syntax error [ILMV pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785624/first-steps-with-javascript-trying-to-debug/3785642#3785642) for you, and they provide a lot more than that.

Answer (score 5):

```
$(document).ready(function() { // <-- missing opening {
    // validate signup form on keyup and submit


    $("#foo").validate({
        rules: {
            'telephone[number]': {
        number: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'telephone[number]': "Please enter a telephone number"

        }
    });
});
```

Look at the first line, [works fine when fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/pFzvb/).

Answer (score 1):

It's because you must have some invalid code which is failing to be parsed by the engine, first step: do you have jQuery loaded?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

was missing at the beginning

Comment: No, it's there, it's just indented wrong and missing the `{` as [ILMV pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785624/first-steps-with-javascript-trying-to-debug/3785642#3785642).

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error, missing { after function(). Also, make sure that you have included jquery.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your program has a syntax error of missing `{` after 
`$(document).ready(function()`